# delete a certain character/characters from files recurrsively in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have 8000 odd files and I need to cleanse them. I am currently using this sed command to replace certain characters with the ones I want:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print | xargs sed -i 's/a/z/g'
```

This recursively changes all the a's in all the files to z. My question is:

1. Can I give multiple characters to be matched in the command to be changed to z?
2. Can I delete the matched character instead of changing it to z?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I give multiple characters to be matched in the command to be changed to z?

Yes, you can. You do that by encasing  multiple characters in square brackets:

```
sed -i 's/[abc]/z/g' file.txt
```

This will replace all **a**, **b**, and **c** characters with **z**.
It will not replace **abc** with **z**, it will replace it with **zzz**.

> Can I delete the matched character instead of changing it to z?

This is very easy, you just replace it with nothing:

```
sed -i 's/[abc]//g' file.txt
```

This will delete all **a**, **b**, and **c** characters.

Note: These examples work in your case with `find` & `xargs` too.

Comment: Thanks @Fanatique...much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Both can be answered yes:

1: You can do that by using a so called character class [abcde], e.g.

`echo abcabcabc | sed -e 's/[abc]/z/g'`

which replaces all three a,b,c by z.

2: If you substitute to empty string, it will basically delete all matching chars, e.g.

`echo abcabcabc | sed -e 's/[ac]//g'`

you only get the b's back.